# Algorithm to remove blanks from a $n \times m$ matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am wondering if it is possible to remove either rows or columns from an n x m matrix which have blanks scattered throughout, with the goal to maximize the amount of cells left, and no blanks.

An example of this is if I have this data

```
1 2 3 _ 4 5
9 7 6 2 _ 3
_ 3 5 _ 7 2
```

by only removing columns 1, 4, and 5 I will get

```
2 3 5
7 6 3
3 5 2
```

which appears to be optimal, but is there a formal way to go about this?

Is it possible to extend this to a large data set too? In this example being so small most solutions are trivial, but for a 10 x 10 it won't be.

Cheers

Comment: Just to be clear, you removed _columns_ 1, 4 and 5.

Comment: Yep. This was just one of the solutions I found with this example I could quickly think of, and then I couldn't find a way to better it.

Comment: For every blank encountered, if(no. of non-blank cells in row containing the blank is more than no. of non-blank cells in column containing the blank) then remove column, else remove row

Comment: @johndoe That might be the optimal thing to do in each single step, but that doesn't automatically mean it gives the optimal result in the end. For instance, if the matrix is $2\times 5$, and there are three blanks in the first row and none in the second, then your algorithm gives the wrong result.

Comment: by swapping rows and columns (I should have mentioned this is fine) this does begin to remind me of something taught many years ago at a-levels, and potentially decision maths, but I can't remember what. Having played with a large example dataset by swapping them so all the blanks are as close to a corner as possible and making go in a diagonal line I appear to be getting somewhere with this, but I'm not sure